# Can you mix record syntax with enumerations in Haskell data types?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I've written the following:

```
data Expression = Expression { lhs :: Int, rhs :: Expression } | Int
```

The problem is if I try to construct an Expression with just an int I get a partially applied function. What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: Your data definition defines a new type constructor (something that lives in the space of types) called `Expression` and two data constructors `Expression` and `Int` (which live in the space of values/functions). The `Int` constructor has no relation to the `Int` type (they live in separate namespaces).

Comment: Did you mean something like `… | Literal { value :: Int }`?

Comment: Yes, I believe this is what I meant. Thanks.

Comment: If you follow this approach, note that the `lhs,rhs` accessors are partial -- they will crash your program if you ever feed them a non-`Expression`. I'd either not define them at all, or use them only in pattern matching as in `foo (Expression{lhs = x}) = ...`. Unfortunately Haskell does not allow to restrict fields only for pattern matching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Things to know up front:

- every data constructor in a Haskell `data` declaration has its own name
- data constructors live in an entirely separate namespace from type names

---

As the comments note, you are defining both a type named `Expression` and a data constructor named `Expression`.  Because Haskell has separate namespaces for types and data constructors, the compiler is fine with this.

Also, you are creating a second data constructor named `Int` (which likewise doesn't conflict with the existing type named `Int`).  This is probably not what you want, and is confusing to boot!

When you try to construct a value such as `myExpr = Expression x y`, you are using the first data constructor, not the type name or the second data constructor.  The `Expression` data constructor expects two arguments: first an `Int`, then an `Expression`.  That is why, if you just provide the first argument, you will get a partially applied function.

---

A corrected, more idiomatic version of your example might be:

```
data Expression = Assignment { lhs :: Int, rhs :: Expression }
                | Literal { value :: Int }
```

It is actually fairly common to see a data constructor with the same name as its type, if it is the *only* data constructor:

```
data Foo = Foo { unwrapFoo :: Int }
```

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completeness, the answer to your question is yes. The other answer provides an excellent explanation of what your current code does, but the short answer to your question is that

```
data Expression = Assignment { lhs :: Int, rhs :: Expression }
                | Literal Int
```

is a completely valid type declaration. That being said, it's not tremendously idiomatic, so if you're going to use record syntax, you should probably use it for each data constructor of a given type.

Comment: This answer would be improved by an explanation of why this type of definition is not tremendously idiomatic.